# jQuery only gets the default value of input

Tags: jquery, button, input, click, show

I have two click events and two buttons. One button is hidden and one input is hidden.

When I click the button that is not hidden, the hidden button and the hidden input appear. When I click the second button, the one that was hidden, I get the default value of the input. This is the problem, it's getting the default value, and by default I mean whatever I typed in the `value='dasad'` in the code. It's not getting the value that the user typed.

Some example code, don't look the syntax just as an example

```
    $(button1).click(funciton(){
     $(button2).show();
    $(input2).show();
    })
    $(button2).click(function(){
    $(input2).val();
    })
```

I tried using `delegate`, but it's the same as the `click` result.

Comment: You'll have to put together a minimal, self-contained example and post the code to the question (and optionally *also* to http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net, but always include the code in the question as well).

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following and was able to get it to work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('#button2').show();
    $('#input2').show();
});
$('#button2').click(function(){
    alert($('#input2').val());
})
});
```

Buttons are setup like

```
<button id="button1">hello</button>
<button id="button2" style="display:none">hello 2</button>
<input id="input2" style="display:none" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('#button2').show();
    $('#input2').show();
    return false;
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
    var value = $('#input2').val();
    alert(value);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation there's really no reason you MUST used delegate but from what I've read it really is never a bad idea.

Here is an example [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/6EHyD/) doing what I think you want, it's a little hard to tell from your question.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wrapper").delegate(".button1", "click", function() {
        $(".innerDiv").show();
        $(".input1").focus();
    });

    $(".wrapper").delegate(".button2", "click", function() {
        $(".showVal").html($(".input1").val());
    });

});
```